# How can I merge my partitions without losing data?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I just bought a new ssd and I want to reinstall windows on it. Right now I have 2 partitions on a 1TB HDD, one with windows, which is 150gb, and the other one is 781GB.

My question is, how can I merge my windows partition with the other one after/while reinstalling windows?

Answer (score 0):

The only effective way to be sure that data is not lost is to **first make a disk image, or at least a backup,** of the disk. There are many tools to do so, such as free [Macrium Relect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), and most such tools can reduce the image size by compression and by storing only used sectors.

Often, combining partitions works flawlessly... but when it doesn't, a disk images is invaluable, and even if all the merger works, you can access individual files in the image to verify that nothing got mangled.